# How to connect host machine from container using nsenter utility

Tags: docker, ubuntu, kubernetes, ubuntu-18.04, nsenter

There is a utility called **nsenter** in ubuntu. nsenter is a small tool allowing to enter into namespaces. It will enter into your docker container. I want to control the host machine from the docker container. How do I connect the host machine from the container using the nsenter utility?

Comment: Seems like ```docker exec -it CONTAINER_NAME /bin/bash``` is a superior way for such task compare to ```nsenter```. Ref: https://github.com/jpetazzo/nsenter

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`nsenter` allows you to join the Linux namespaces of a targeted process id (PID).

First, run a container that shares your hosts PID namespace with `--pid=host`. The container has to be privileged with `--privileged`, otherwise executing `nsenter` will fail with an "Operation not permitted" error. The container is kept running indefinitely by executing `tail -f /dev/null`.

```
docker run --pid=host --privileged --name admin-container ubuntu:latest tail -f /dev/null
```

Then exec into the container with `nsenter`, entering the file system, ipc, utc and network namespace of the host machine's very first init process (PID = 1):

```
docker exec -it admin-container nsenter --target 1 --mount --uts --ipc --net /bin/bash
```

Have a look around and you will notice, you are on the host machine.

Comment: ("If you disable Docker's security controls, then you can escape the container.")

Comment: I guess the whole purpose of using nsenter is to escape the container (for admin purposes), right?

Comment: @FritzDuchardt Thank you for your answer. Could you please explain what is the meaning of "tail -f /dev/null" in the above command.

Comment: @AshokKumar sure - I have added a short explanation to my answer: it's to keep the container running.